# How to auto import vcf file to android and iOS device from website button

Tags: php, html, vcf-vcard

In website, I have a anchor link for the vcf file. In android it downloads the file and then manually in need to save it. In Iphone it open directly but not auto imported the contact. Is there is any option to autosave the .vcf file to the mobile contact.

HTML Code

```
    <div class=button>
        <a href="<?php echo $base_url?>bcard/hamzeh.vcf">Add to Contact</a>
    </div>
```

.VCF File

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.1//EN
N:User;Test;;;
FN:Test User
ORG:Company Name
TITLE:Designation
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=Email;type=pref:test@test.com
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:+9626262622
item1.URL;type=pref:https://test.com
item1.X-ABLabel:Website
item2.ADR;type=Office: #1, 1st St, Test location
item2.X-ABLabel:Address
END:VCARD
```

Expected result - The .vcf should be autosaved to the mobile contact.

Comment: That would probably be more of a device-specific setting, than anything you can specify from your end, I would assume.